# Ajax not loading correct data into bootstrap modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap, codeigniter

I want to dynamically load form into bootstrap modal but the modal is just spitting  code of the main page.

CODE: Client

```
     $('.bookBut').click(function(e){


  // create url
  var uri = "services/bookService/"+this.id;

 // make ajax call and load data into modal body

  $.ajax({
           url:uri,
           cache:false,
           success:function(data){
             alert(data);
             $('#bookModalBody').html(data);
             $('#loginBookModal').modal("show");
          },
          error:function(error){
            $('#bookModalBody').html("Sorry, some error occured.           <br/>Come back soon.");
             $('#loginBookModal').modal("show");

          }
    });
  });
```

Server:

```
  public function bookService($serviceIid){


           if($this->session->userdata('cityId')==false || isset($serviceId)==false){ // user has not selected any city

                               // some way to redirect user to select city

                       }
           if(!$this->session->userdata('userId')){  // user not logged in

                $this->load->model('Model_users');

                $data['forms']=$this->Model_users->login();

                $this->load->view('view_login',$data);
            }
      }
```

When I directly hit the url from browser, I am getting the correct output, but the ajax call is returning code of my main page.

Comment: What exactly does `$this->Model_users->login();` return?

Comment: It creates the forms and return it as an associative array, my view uses that array to create all the forms. I can not figure why ajax is not hitting the URL. When I type my url directly in browser I am getting the output.

Comment: Try making `var uri` into an absolute URL.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(!$this->session->userdata('userId')){  // user not logged in

            $this->load->model('Model_users');

            $data['forms']=$this->Model_users->login();

            return $this->load->view('view_login',$data);
        }
```

You are not returning the view :)

Comment: I am rendering the view, so return should not be necessary. Anyway, I tried it, still the same problem.